# Parse HTML table in file to csv with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm a Python noob and even bigger BeautifulSoup and html noob. I have a file downloaded that has an html table in it. In all the examples of BeautifulSoup parsing I have seen, they all use urllib to access the table url and then the read the response and pass it to BeautifulSoup to parse. My question is, for a locally stored file, do I have to load the entire file into memory? So instead of doing say:

```
    contenturl = "http://www.bank.gov.ua/control/en/curmetal/detail/currency?period=daily"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())
```

Do I instead do:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/home/dir/filename').read())
```

That doesn't really seem to work. So I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My apologies if its something really silly I'm doing but help is appreciated

Update: Issue is resolved, need to import class from module for BeautifulSoup. Thank you!

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work"? `BeautifulSoup` needs html, from any source is fine. If you get any errors, please post them here?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  What happened?

Comment: Also, the `BeautifulSoup` constructor can also take a `file` object, so you don't need the `.read()` at the end.

Comment: So its throwing the following error: EOL while scanning string literal: <string>, line 1, pos 117

Comment: What does `open('/home/dir/filename').read()` return? Please post it in the question.

Comment: So the EOL error was something silly I fixed. I edited the question, it might still be something very silly but thanks for the help!

Comment: Post the entire traceback please, which has the file-names..

Comment: Ok the issue is resolved. I needed to import the class from the module BeautifulSoup. My apologies if I wasted your time. Thanks for your help!